# Takusen: truncation error

Tags: haskell

I wrote a small script to extract data from Oracle using Takusen:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Test where

import Database.Oracle.Enumerator
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Connections (watDevDb, watProdDb)
import System.Environment
import Data.Char

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [fn] <- getArgs
  sqls <- readFile fn
  flip catchDB reportRethrow (withSession watProdDb $ do
         let iter (c1::Maybe String) (c2::Maybe String) (c3::Maybe String) (r::Maybe String) = result' c3
         rslt <- doQuery (sql sqls) iter (Nothing::Maybe String)
         liftIO (putStrLn . show $ rslt))

test = withArgs ["extract.sql"] main
```

`c2` and `c3` are CLOB-s
When I try to execute it, I get the following error message:

`*** Exception: DBError ("01","000") 1406 " : ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated\n"`

It turned out that `c3` is the problematic one. When I exclude it from query, it works just fine.
Judging by the error, I need to increase buffer size for `c3` to avoid truncation but I cannot find anything like that in Takusen documentation.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted authors of Takusen and got the following response (Oleg) :

> bindBuffer is indeed not relevant to the problem at hand: bindBuffers
>   are used when binding data to query variables, that is, moving data
>   *into* the database. Buffer allocation for data *from* the database is
>   done in the instances of the class DBType. There are several instances
>   in
>       .../takusen/Database/Oracle/Enumerator.lhs
>   The relevant one, for the column type Maybe String, is
>
> instance DBType (Maybe String) Query ColumnBuffer where
>    allocBufferFor _ q n = allocBuffer q (16000, oci_SQLT_CHR) n
>    fetchCol q buffer = bufferToString buffer
>
> It seems the allocated buffer is 16000 bytes. Perhaps that number
>   should be increased.

The increase of this buffer solved my problem.

Many thanks to Oleg et al.

Answer (score 1):

A quick browse through the takusen code reveals a hardcoded constant :-(

From: http://code.haskell.org/takusen/Database/Oracle/Enumerator.lhs

```
instance OracleBind String where
   -- FIXME  should these be withUTF8String{Len} ?
   bindWithValue v a = withCString v (\p -> a (castPtr p))
   bindWriteBuffer b s = withCStringLen s (\(p,l) -> 
     copyBytes (castPtr b) p (1+l))
   bindDataSize s = fromIntegral (length s)
   bindBufferSize _ = 32000
   bindType _ = oci_SQLT_CHR
```

But that's easy enough to work around, or would be if OracleBind was an exported class

```
newtype SomeHugeString = SomeHugeString {getHugeString :: String}
instance OracleBind SomeHugeString where ...
```

As is, I think you'll have to just create your own fork of the /Oracle/Enumerator.lhs file.

Comment: It seems strange, but I cranked it up to 524288 and it still throws the same error :-(